# Sending/Storing credentials in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies, nsurlrequest

I have an iPhone app that uses an `NSURLRequest` to sign in to a web app. In order to make a particular request later down the line, it needs the cookie received when the user logged in, to verify the user's identity. As I understand it, cookies are automatically stored. However, when I send the request, I'm getting a failed request. Is there anything I need to do when creating my new request to specify to look for the given cookie? Is there any way to ensure that the cookie is being stored at all when the login request is sent?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: I was discussing the same thing with @TimStone in the MSO Tavern yesterday. We didn't get into specifics, but I suggest looking into a  library that will cache the credentials/cookie/token/whatever for you.

Comment: To be a bit more secure, you may try just returning a session id string from your authentication web service and then presenting that on each request rather than relying on storing the user id information on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem wasn't with the cookie not being stored or sent. It's stored as I expected. The problem was coming from a badly formatted URL involving quotes.

Thanks!